# Keyboard shows when getting an incoming call

Tags: keyboard, calls, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4

I have an LG Nexus 4 running Android 4.2.1 and have a strange problem. When I got an incoming phone call the keyboard is displayed and won't go away. This is a rather big problem since it obscures the area which allows me to accept the phone call.

Is there anyway in which I can stop this happening? This is my first Android device so I am still pretty new to it.

Comment: How did you manage that? The only time the keyboard *should* appear, is either in a application that has a input focus prompting for keyboard input... is the ROM stock or custom?

Comment: @t0mm13b I have no idea :). Everything about the phone is completely stock. I haven't done any modifications to it at all.

Comment: Same problem. I figured that this happens only if you use password as a Screen lock. Any other Screen lock feature works (including pin).